# Prdicting Y when we have some pattern in input text using ML?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, data-science

I have a data set of around 20k in which I have 13k unique dependent variable in this 20k. My data looks like this:

```
       Pattern        Y

0 dd AN dd AN dd AN    Y1
1 dd AN dd AN dd AN    Y1
2 a omnes              Y2
3 agence reuters ralr agence retr sarl   Y3
```

Similarly 20k+ observation. So in production, I have to predict Y during production once this pattern data is coming.

My problem is I don't have lot of observations for each unique dependent variable (like 1-5 observations for some or most of the time it is 1).

**My approach**

I am using tf-idf and training my model on Naive byes. I am getting good accuracy like around 70%.

**My problem**

I am afraid because I have to train this on like 1-5 observations, so even in little variation in input might create lot bias in output.

So can anybody tell me the best approach for this problem which can go to production?

Comment: The example you gave has 1 to 1 relationship between a particular pattern (dd AN dd AN dd AN) and its class (Y1). There is no variation of patterns for a class. In this case, you don't machine learning, just a simple dictionary lookup will do. Suggest you update your example to show different patterns for the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Try generating additional observations via code to test robustness of your model.

How many different tokens do you have in your input?

Write a function to randomly generate patterns by mixing and matching tokens (e.g. dd, AN, agence, reuters, ralr, sarl) to generate new patterns. You can also add some new tokens (e.g xyzr) in the generated patterns that model has not seen before.

Generate about a 100 patterns like this and then test your model. This would give you an idea of how sensitive is your model to variation that it has not been trained on.

You can tweak this synthetic pattern code to test the variations that you are most worried about encountering in production